# Multiple hits in an inning by a pitcher

Tags: baseball, records

Today against the Atlanta Braves, Washington Nationals pitcher Stephen Strasburg started the third inning with a single and later hit a three-run home run in that same inning. When was the last time a pitcher got two hits as a hitter in the same inning? Is there a list of all such occurrences?

Comment: Here's a [list, but it's only covers up to 2010](https://www.baseball-fever.com/forum/general-baseball/trivia/68705-pitcher-with-two-hits-in-the-same-inning)

Answer (score -1):

Edwin Jackson got 2 hits in one inning with one being a home run in 2010.

ref. https://www.espn.com/mlb/story/_/id/27218318/strasburg-gets-2-hits-one-inning-including-hr

Comment: Please provide a source to your answer

Comment: This definitely isn't correct; the list provided in the comments of OP explicitly mentions one later (Bumgarner, later that year).